# Kivy basic button program doesnt work

Tags: button, kivy

I am trying to make my first app in kivy so i copied a basic button code.

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn = Button(text="Press me")
        return btn

if name == 'main':
    TestApp().run()
```

however the button doesnt seem to be pressed when i click it with my mouse.

any suggestions how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: If your code is formatted like this, it should not work

Comment: it is actually indented right, is there any other problem?

Comment: After fixing indentation and correcting `if name == 'main':` to `if __name__ == '__main__':` it works for me.

Comment: its also like you wrote, the forum made it this way automatically. any ideas why it doesnt work for me? maybe i need to install something so that it actually responds to my button click? i mean, it does compile and show me the button but it doesnt respond to my button click

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyButton(Button):

    def on_release(self):
        print("Button pressed!")


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyButton(text="Press me!")


MyApp().run()
```

This should work with python 2 and 3, and Kivy installed. Nothing extra needed.
If this does not work for you, I would try to reinstall [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#download).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I did try this out and it does show the Press me text, however when I click this with left mouse click it does nothing. If really nothing extra is needed im going to try to reinstall

Comment: @matanPeleg you are wellcome.

Comment: I actually tried the pong example in kivy examples and it does run but does not respond to any user input. I guess something is indeed broken there

Comment: @matanPeleg yes, in that case I would try to reinstall. Should work with mouse and everything from default.

Comment: @matanPeleg what OS are you on?

Comment: Im using windows. the only installation process ive done are the 4 steps on this page https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html  perhaps im missing something? @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @matanPeleg python 2 or 3?

Comment: im using python 2.7

Comment: @matanPeleg ok. That should work with those 4 steps. Try reinstall both python2.7 and kivy then

Comment: @matanPeleg you are wellcome :)